# Return row of every n'th record

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

How can I return every *nth* record from a sub query based on a numerical parameter that I supply?

For example, I may have the following query:

```
SELECT
   Id,
   Key
FROM DataTable
WHERE CustomerId = 1234
ORDER BY Key
```

**e.g.**

The subquery result may look like the following:

```
Row Id   Key
1   1    A3231
2   43   C1212
3   243  E1232
4   765  G1232
5   2432 E2325
...
90  3193 F2312
```

If I pass in the number 30, and the sub query result set contained 90 records, I would recieve the *30th*, *60th*, and *90th* row.

If I pass in the number 40, and the result set contained 90 records, I would recieve the *40th* and *80th* row.

*As a side note, for background information, this is being used to capture the key/id of every nth record for a paging control.*

Comment: Note that without an `ORDER BY`, you will get the results in a random order, so you may as well just limit to the *first* N results.

Comment: @Oli Thanks, forgot to add that.  The results will always be in the same order, and will never change.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This is where [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) can help. It requires an order-by clause but this is okay because an order-by is present (and required to guarantee a particular order).

```
SELECT t.id, t.key
FROM
(
    SELECT id, key, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY key) AS rownum
    FROM datatable
) AS t
WHERE t.rownum % 30 = 0    -- or % 40 etc
ORDER BY t.key
```

Comment: @pst: The `ROW_NUMBER` windowing function isn't a proprietary TSQL extension. It's part of the SQL standard (since SQL2003, I believe).

Comment: looks like it http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/sql/0596004818/sql-functions/sqlnut2-chp-4-sect-3

Answer (score 13):

You don't have to use row number, any integer field will do. On most tables we have an autonumber field. For simplicity, I will call it ID. To display every 13th record:

```
Select ID, LastName, FirstName FROM Users WHERE ID%13 = 0 ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: If a row is deleted presumably this will no longer work?

Comment: Thanks, this simple solution works for my purposes (I am constructing a general test data set so any missing deleted items are not a concern for me)

Comment: This doesn't help if query is filtered with WHERE clauses as then ID jumps up randomly.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select B.name 
from (Select row_number() over (order by ordering) as row_num, 
      A.name 
      from (Select name,'P1' as ordering 
            from [dbo].[every_2nd_record]
           ) A
      ) B
where B.row_num%2=0
```