# Return Row of Every Nth Record

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, syntax-error

I'm trying to developer the Oracle SQL version of the accepted answer here:
[Return row of every n'th record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799816/return-row-of-every-nth-record)

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT ROW_ID, CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID
FROM
(
    SELECT CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID as CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID) AS ROW_ID
    FROM XXDMX_VOICE_CUSTOMERS_TBL
) AS t
WHERE ROW_ID % 10000 = 0   
ORDER BY CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID;
```

I get the error

ERROR
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I've tried lots of variations and can't think of what I am doing wrong. Any ideas, Oracle experts?

Answer (score 2):

Try writing the query like this:

```
SELECT rn, CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID
FROM (SELECT CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID as CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID) AS rn
      FROM XXDMX_VOICE_CUSTOMERS_TBL
     ) t
WHERE mod(rn, 10000) = 0   
ORDER BY CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID;
```

The primary difference is removing the `as` for the table alias.  Oracle doesn't allow this syntax.  I also changed `row_id` to something else, because "rowid" means something in Oracle and its use could be confusing (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm)).

Comment: Hmm. I get ERROR
ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: Got it. You have to use MOD instead of % see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm

Answer (score 1):

In PL/SQL (the name for "Oracle SQL"), the modulus operator uses this syntax:

```
WHERE MOD(ROW_ID, 10000) = 0
```