# Rails Active Record - Get an evenly distributed arbitrary number of records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to have queries on my rails App that return an evenly distributed arbitrary number of records.

What means is, if my query returns 100 records and I want only 4, it should return the records 100, 75, 50 and 25.
If I want 5, it should return 100, 80, 60, 40, 20.

I know I could do it manipulating an array after the result, but my question is, is there a way to do it directly with ActiveRecord or even SQL?

Comment: You can use modulo operator in SQL. Will try to find a suitable solution and post it in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on postgresql, mssql or oracle, you can use the row_number() function but it looks like you'll need two nested queries, which might be more complicated than you want.  See [Return row of every n'th record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799816/return-row-of-every-nth-record) for an example of how to construct it.

From there, what you're trying to do might look like:

```
MyModel.find_by_sql("
   select * from my_models where id in (
     SELECT t.id
     FROM
     (
         SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rownum
         FROM my_models
         WHERE [YOUR CONDITIONS HERE]
     ) AS t
     WHERE t.rownum % n = 0
     ORDER BY t.key
   )")
```

It's really hard to tell from here how expensive that query might be.  If I might offer some advice, I would really suggest proving that you have a performance problem doing it the Rails way, before getting into trying an optimization like this.

You can avoid having to fetch and deserialize all the records you'd skip, by using the [ids method of an AREL query object](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ids) to get only the ids like so:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  class < self
    def get_each_n_of_query(n)
      all_ids = get_query.ids
      ids = (0... all_ids.length).select{ |x| x%n == n-1 }.map { |y| all_ids[y] }
      where(id: ids)
    end

    def get_query()
      where(foo: 'bar', ...)
    end
  end
end
```

Credit to the answers at [How do you select every nth item in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689186/how-do-you-select-every-nth-item-in-an-array) for how to divide the list of ids.

Comment: Hey @tyler. Thanks for the answer. I'll give it a try today. What I was trying to check if it's possible to avoid, is to query for a lot of records and only then to cherrypick the ones I want. I'm afraid to lose performance when a query hits half a million rows or so. But I think the `ROW_NUMBER()` will be good enough :)

Answer (score 0):

I may have misread the question, but I was trying to solve a similar question and used:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [column]
FROM [table]
ORDER BY [column] [DESC|ASC]
OFFSET @Row-1 ROWS --you send @Row a row value if you want to start on Nth row down e.g. 10 to start at row 10
FETCH NEXT @Rows ROWS ONLY --the number of rows you want to see
```